# Rreferences for free groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, free-groups

I have done free groups. I studied it from Rotman two semesters back. But this semester I am doing combinatorial group theory and obviously it starts with free groups. I have to revise Free groups but I have never got a  good intution about free groups and always have been on backfoot with them whenever have studied them. This time in one month break Ii have before semester starts I want to Free groups and all related concepts used for combinatorial group theory so that I can do well with combinatorial group theory and can get into the subject deep. Any good conceptual/elaborate references? Please suggest some books. Thanks

Comment: The super classics in combinatorial group theory: the books by Magnus-Karrasar-Solitar, and by Lyndon-Schupp. You also have the books by Cohen, by Baumslag and by Shafarevich-Parshin.

Comment: to start Chapter 7 of M. Hall's "Group Theory".